# Update only if key exist firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that counts all the members that are going to do a event.

I have the registered_people key to count how many users are on this event. This key is updated +1 or -1 when someone adds itself to the /registrations/approved link.

This works very well. See the method below.

```
exports.reservation = functions.database.ref('/agenda/activitys/{year}/{month}/{day}/{time}/{event}/registrations/approved/{key}').onWrite((event) => {
        var collectionRef = event.data.adminRef.parent.parent;
        var countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('registered_people');

    console.log("Fired of reservation watcher");

    return countRef.transaction(function(current) {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) + 1;
        }
        else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (current || 0) - 1;
        }
    });
});
```

But my problem is when the admin deletes an event. Url `/agenda/activitys/{year}/{month}/{day}/{time}/{event}` gets deleted, and the method defined above gets triggered and writes data again to the url. How can I prevent that this method writes anything when an admin deletes the event?

And this code is not working:

```
if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
    return;
  }
```

Because when a user wants to sign out from an event the registered_people must be updated. With the code defined above the delete does not work anymore. So I need to check if the event is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are running and old version of functions & admin, update to be sure your firebase-functions & firebase-admin are updated:

In your functions folder run:

> ```
> npm install firebase-functions@latest --save 
> npm install firebase-admin@latest --save
> ```

Then your code should look like this:

```
exports.reservation = functions.database.ref('/agenda/activitys/{year}/{month}/{day}/{time}/{event}/registrations/approved/{key}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  var collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent.parent;
  var countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('registered_people');
  let increment;
  if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
    increment = 1;
  } else if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  return countRef.transaction((current) => {
    return (current || 0) + increment;
  }).then(() => {
    return console.log('Counter updated.');
  });
});
```